# how to request.form data pass in unit price for asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
        productInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
        productInfo.category = Request.Form["category"];
        productInfo.color = Request.Form["color"];
       // productInfo.unit_price = Request.Form["unit_price"];

        productInfo.unit_price = 0.01M;
```

there is someting wrong with this
how to currect this line for unit price

please currect this column unit price

Comment: "there is someting wrong with this" What exactly? Are you getting an error? If so, what's the message? And why are you working with `Request.Form` instead of ModelBinding: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.